# Manually Get Cached Tiles in Mapsforge

Tags: android, cordova, mapsforge

I'm developing a map application with **leaflet** in **phonegap** and I am targeting **android** devices so I decided to use **mapsforge**.

I want to use MapsForge tile caching and tile rendering (from mapsforge .map files).

I just don't know what exact methods to call.
[Here](https://github.com/zachswain/MapCacheView) is an old phonegap plugin written with mapsforge 0.2.4, which is no longer supported in mapsforge 0.4.x.

I want to request for tiles with x, y and z parameters to get the cached tile and if there is no available cache tile, render it and then cache it to both **memory (ram)** and **sd card**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since no gentleman answered the question, I figured it out how to do it!

I have created a new repository on github for my plugin.

I used mapsforge 0.4.0 and phonegap 3.4.0.
Here is the repository : https://github.com/Arman92/Mapsforge-Phonegap-OfflineCache

I'd be happy to answer any question ;)

EDIT:
I recently wrote a blog post about [Offline tile rendering using mapsforge in phonegap](http://armansafikhani.ir/weblog/2014/august/offline-maps-using-mapsforge-in-cordova-android-app)